# RDBMS - Lock Table to prevent Inserts

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I would like to be able to lock a table to prevent other users doing Inserts. I don't want to lock the whole table, because this would prevent other users from updating rows. I do have another reasonably elegant solution, however if I could lock the table solely to prevent another user inserting rows, that would be a better solution. IE. Any user before attempting an INSERT would attempt to acquire this lock, and wait if already in use.

Comment: It might help to actually explain the purpose of why you are trying to do this. What is the purpose of preventing inserts, but allowing updates?

Comment: I need to generate my own unique key, and I cannot use the auto serial key generated by the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your trying to do this but I believe you can accomplish what your doing by locking on a dummy table.

That is for all inserts you would not actually lock on the table that you want to insert but on a different table that you use only for locks:

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE insert_locks IN EXCLUSIVE;
INSERT INTO real_table VALUES
    (_id_, 'GREAT! I was waiting for it for so long!');
COMMIT WORK;
```

[See Postgres' doc on LOCK](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-lock.html).

Unfortunately you will have to go change any code that is doing inserts with out locking. The other option is to use some sort of [Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) which I have done many times with great success.

Comment: Another option would be to use advisory locks in Postgres. Less "heavy" than a table lock.

Comment: @Adam. I'm doing something similar, I'm locking a record in another Table containing a record for any table where I want to achieve this lock. That has the advantage that it is RDBMS independent as compared to table locks where they may differ between RDBMS's. I was hoping for an in-memory locking mechanism that does not require a SELECT FOR UPDATE. The record lock is released with the COMMIT or ROLLBACK. I'll look up the "advisory locks", but they may be specific to Postgres.

Comment: Hmm all that for unique keys... I would just use UUIDs. Making UUID's may not be fast but its sure faster than locking on a bunch of tables.

Comment: @Adam. It is very fast (relative of course), and it's better than locking-out updates which is where the main activity is. I will do more testing, but there seems to be little or no impact on performance compared to auto-inc sequences, and there are no "lost" keys.

Comment: @Adam. I'll tick your answer, because it's basically the same as what I'm doing, and would work.